# Не работает форма обратной связи на beget

Tags: php

Не работает форма обратной связи (не приходят сообщения на почту), хотя сообщения на локальном сервере отправляет.
Код в форме html:

```
<div id="myModal" class="modal fade">
            <div class="modal-dialog">
                <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                        <button class="close" type="button" data-dismiss="modal"><i class="far fa-window-close"></i></button>

                    </div>
    <h4 class="modal-title">Get your number here</h4>
        <form id="contact-form" method="post" action="contact.php" role="form">

    <div class="messages"></div>

    <div class="controls">

        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <input id="form_name" type="text" name="name" class="call-control" placeholder="Please enter your firstname *" required="required" data-error="Firstname is required.">
                    <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-12">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <input id="form_lastname" type="text" name="surname" class="call-control" placeholder="Please enter your lastname *" required="required" data-error="Lastname is required.">
                    <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-12">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <input id="form_email" type="e-mail" name="email" class="call-control" placeholder="Please enter your email *" required="required" data-error="Valid email is required.">
                    <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-12">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <textarea id="form_message" name="message" class="call-control" placeholder="Message for me *" rows="4" required="required" data-error="Please, leave us a message."></textarea>
                    <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-12">
                <input type="submit" class="btn btn-success btn-send button-main button-modal" value="Send message">
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-12">
                <p class="text-muted">
                    <strong>*</strong> These fields are required.</p>
            </div>
    </div>
</div>
</form>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

На php:

```
<?php
/*
 *  CONFIGURE EVERYTHING HERE
 */

// an email address that will be in the From field of the email.
$from = 'Demo contact form <demo@domain.com>';

// an email address that will receive the email with the output of the form
$sendTo = 'layraldo@gmail.com';

// subject of the email
$subject = 'New message from contact form';

// form field names and their translations.
// array variable name => Text to appear in the email
$fields = array('name' => 'Name', 'surname' => 'Surname', 'phone' => 'Phone', 'email' => 'Email', 'message' => 'Message'); 

// message that will be displayed when everything is OK :)
$okMessage = 'Contact form successfully submitted. Thank you, I will get back to you soon!';

// If something goes wrong, we will display this message.
$errorMessage = 'There was an error while submitting the form. Please try again later';


/*
 *  LET'S DO THE SENDING
 */

// if you are not debugging and don't need error reporting, turn this off by error_reporting(0);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);

error_reporting(E_ALL & ~E_NOTICE);

try
{

    if(count($_POST) == 0) throw new \Exception('Form is empty');

    $emailText = "You have a new message from your contact form\n=============================\n";

    foreach ($_POST as $key => $value) {
        // If the field exists in the $fields array, include it in the email 
        if (isset($fields[$key])) {
            $emailText .= "$fields[$key]: $value\n";
        }
    }

    // All the neccessary headers for the email.
    $headers = array('Content-Type: text/plain; charset="UTF-8";',
        'From: ' . $from,
        'Reply-To: ' . $from,
        'Return-Path: ' . $from,
    );

    // Send email
    mail($sendTo, $subject, $emailText, implode("\n", $headers));

    $responseArray = array('type' => 'success', 'message' => $okMessage);
}
catch (\Exception $e)
{
    $responseArray = array('type' => 'danger', 'message' => $errorMessage);
}


// if requested by AJAX request return JSON response
if (!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) && strtolower($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) == 'xmlhttprequest') {
    $encoded = json_encode($responseArray);

    header('Content-Type: application/json');

    echo $encoded;
}
// else just display the message
else {
    echo $responseArray['message'];
}
```

И js:

```
$(function () {

    // init the validator
    // validator files are included in the download package
    // otherwise download from http://1000hz.github.io/bootstrap-validator

    $('#contact-form').validator();


    // when the form is submitted
    $('#contact-form').on('submit', function (e) {

        // if the validator does not prevent form submit
        if (!e.isDefaultPrevented()) {
            var url = "contact.php";

            // POST values in the background the the script URL
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: url,
                data: $(this).serialize(),
                success: function (data)
                {
                    // data = JSON object that contact.php returns

                    // we recieve the type of the message: success x danger and apply it to the 
                    var messageAlert = 'alert-' + data.type;
                    var messageText = data.message;

                    // let's compose Bootstrap alert box HTML
                    var alertBox = '<div class="alert ' + messageAlert + ' alert-dismissable"><button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>' + messageText + '</div>';

                    // If we have messageAlert and messageText
                    if (messageAlert && messageText) {
                        // inject the alert to .messages div in our form
                        $('#contact-form').find('.messages').html(alertBox);
                        // empty the form
                        $('#contact-form')[0].reset();
                    }
                }
            });
            return false;
        }
    })
});
```

Comment: Обратитесь в тех. поддержку хостинга. Если на локалке отправляет а на сайте нет - в первую очередь проверьте настройки сервера

Comment: Что-то консоль пишет при отправке?